# Exim: DKIM: signing failed: PRIVKEY

Tags: exim, dkim

Does anyone know what this error message means and how to fix it? Every time I send an email, I get the following messages in `/var/log/exim4/paniclog`:

```
signing_init: privkey PEM-block import: The requested data were not available.
DKIM: signing failed: PRIVKEY
```

This is my DKIM configuration in `/etc/exim4/conf.d/main/00_local_macros` (with `example.com` replaced with my domain):

```
DKIM_DOMAIN = 'example.com'
DKIM_SELECTOR = '20200601'
DKIM_PRIVATE_KEY = '/etc/exim4/dkim/example.com-private.pem'
DKIM_FILE = '/etc/exim4/dkim/example.com-private.pem'
DKIM_CANON = 'relaxed'
```

`example.com-private.pem` exists, is owned by `root`, and in group `Debian-exim` with permissions 640.

Comment: `openssl rsa -in server.key -check /etc/exim4/dkim/example.com-private.pem`

Comment: ```openssl rsa -in /etc/exim4/dkim/example.com-private.pem -check``` gives:
```RSA key ok
writing RSA key
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----```

Comment: did you solve this? I got same problem in debian bulleye

Comment: I have not solved this.

Comment: I solved this by chmodding the pem file to 640 and making it owned by root:Debian-exim.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, and fixed it by just tweaking the filepath a litte. According to https://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch-dkim_spf_srs_and_dmarc.html#SECDKIMSIGN you could even paste the entire key there.
Try to put the file in the same directory as your `exim4.conf`, with same permissions (i.e. no subdirectory).

Finally, I'm now using:

```
DKIM_PRIVATE_KEY=${if exists{CONFDIR/private.pem}{CONFDIR/private.pem}{0}}
```

... which means: "If you can't read the private key, don't sign the message."

BTW: `DKIM_FILE` means nothing, you can remove it. (Some tutorials are using such a variable to resolve the final path of the private key.)